# Another word for "negatively affected"

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

is there a word that can be used instead of negatively affected. For example if two companies merged and many people lost their jobs in the process. I want to refer to those who lost their jobs as negatively affected by the merge. someone who suffer consequences of an action or an event.

I was going to use "the disadvateged" or " the hurt" but the first s not even a word and the second seems unfit to describe what am trying to say.

Another example

Comment: You really need to include a sample sentence showing how the word you're looking for will be used.  Context is very important in being able to offer suggestions, not to mention knowing what sort of word (noun, adjective, etc.) you are looking for.

Comment: How about "those harmed by the merger"?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't necessarily want to highlight that these people were affected *negatively*, you could simply refer to them as *those **impacted*** by the merger.  From the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[impacted](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impacted)***
>
> **ADJECTIVE**
>
> 2. Strongly affected by something.
>
>    *‘the planners' lamentable failure to consult with the impacted population’*

(Note that I omitted definition 1 which has to do with medical issues.)

Also, I think the word you were looking for is *[disadva**n**taged](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disadvantaged)*.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may use the term ***[victims](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/victim)*** in the case you are suggesting:

> someone or something that has been hurt, damaged, or killed or has suffered, either because of the actions of someone or something else, or because of illness or chance.
>
> - Our local hospital has become the latest victim of the cuts in government spending.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

- The people who lost their jobs are the obvious victims of the merger between the two companies.

Answer (score 2):

That is a complicated question.  the answer depends on the perspective of the writer and, indeed the intended audience.

1. The phrase ‘*negatively affected*’ has the studied, even laboured neutrality of a company officer striving neither to ignore the ‘losers’ nor offer up any hostages to future trouble.  The phrase is neutral to the point of clumsy oxymoron.  What on earth is a ‘negative advantage’?

The more convincing neutral statement, say, from a regulator of mergers would be ‘adversely affected.’. It is straightforward and unemotional.  It is, in the U.K., a common way of referring to this all too common aspect of the merger world.

If you are writing in the context of journalism, it might further depend on your ideology.  ‘Victim’ would fill the bill for someone to the left of centre or otherwise opposed to the merger.